# Should I learn SQL Server 2008 or Oracle 11g

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle

I have been using MySQL for my school projects, personal web site for years.
My company is using MySQL in all web projects as well.

Now I am thinking to pay for some classes to learn another new Database system, but
I have no idea whether I shall choose MS SQL Server 2008 or Oracle 11g.
I hope to find a better job with high paid salary.

I need some advice and suggestions.

Comment: @kwokwai - have you tried searching job sites on the web to see which DB is more in demand in your area?

Comment: Thanks Mark. Most of the results showed me MySQL in the job web site I have heard of

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless Oracle is giving away downloads of 11G for you to learn on, I'd say that Oracle will be a [pricey path](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/database/index.html) to take.  They don't list prices that I can see on the web site.  (Maybe I didn't look hard enough.)  Oracle DBA certification is another expensive proposition.  I think it's rigorous, so it might be worth having, but it'll cost you in courses and test fees.

SQL Server won't cost as much.  You can download [Express for free](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/pricing.aspx).  I'm sure it won't help you with all the enterprise features that will be missing.

Comment: There's an "express" [10g](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/express-edition/overview/index.html). Having used both though, I found SqlServer to be much more accessible and easier to learn.

Comment: If I recall correctly the news in 11G is on the enterprise stuff that is not available in express editions anyway, thus no 11G express was released since it would be more or less identical to 10G express.

Comment: If it's only for testing and learning, Oracle 11g can be downloaded for free

Answer (score 5):

if you are a java developer i think Oracle 11g is better, 
or if you are a .net developer ms sql would be a better choice.

Answer (score 5):

Both MS SQL and Oracle has "express editions" which are somewhat restricted, but free versions that you can try at home. Pick the one you like the most.
The salary will depend more on how good you are than the system you pick (why not both?).

Answer (score 1):

You certainly should not pay in order to learn a new database system. You can get a free version of MS SQL Server Express together with Management Studio on the web. There are loads and loads of materials and tutorials on the web on MS SQL Server. I bet the same can be said about Oracle. In general, go out there and explore the web, it's a much better way to learn than paying for some courses, which might not give you what you need.

Comment: The advantage of such classes is that you usually get a certificate of some sort (however useless it may be) at the end. To employers this often is a better initial selling point than just writing "Some knowledge of <Foo>" on the resumé.

Comment: The question is: do you want to work for a company which will judge your skills based on the certificates you have and not by interviews/skill tests?

Answer (score 0):

It can also depend on your area and what you are trying to get into.  It seems like certain segments of the business world use MSSQL or Oracle exclusively.   I would say that MSSQL is easier to get into but that's just opinion.  Overall it seems like there's more MSSQL jobs but the oracle jobs pay a little better...but again that's a very person experience.  I don't think you'd go wrong with either direction.  I would agree with the others though that you should just download the free versions and play around a little and see which ones catches your attention more and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Let's revert roles.  I ask the question and you answer.

My question to you is "Should I learn to drive a Ford or should I learn to drive a chevy".

The answer is the same because the question is the same, the tiny and irrelevant difference of problem domain notwithstanding.

Answer (score 0):

You should learn oracle as oracle is bitter complex to learn where as SQL Servers is easy becoz of GUI..once you hands on with oracle,,it is easier to learn SQL Server.As a DBA you should have the knowledge of both the DBses...expertise in oracle and minor knowledge of sql server...

Comment: Please pay attention to the date of the original question.  This question was answered nearly a year ago with an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out guys .It is very useful .Share with your friends.
http://www.blogger.com/blogger.g?blogID=199110802022460749#editor/target=post;postID=7162651198801267960